# ¿Como separo una columna <chr> en otras mediante comas?

Tags: r, dataframe

tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo un Df con datos de docentes y en una columna las áreas en las que trabajan, que son varias. Estas áreas están separadas por comas por ejemplo "Matemáticas, programación, estadística aplicada" etc.
Entonces hice el siguiente código

```
df %>% 
  separate(Areas, into = c("linea1", "linea2", "linea3", "linea4", "linea5",
  "linea6", "linea7","linea8", "linea9", "linea10", sep = '\\,' ))
```

Pero esto, por ejemplo para alguien que tiene en la columna Areas
**Teoría de Control Óptimo, Teoría de Juegos** me lo separa de la siguiente manera

```
teor  | a   |de   | control    | ptimo   | teor    | a   | de   | juegos   | NA
```

con la división del | me refiero a que me lo divide en varias columas cuando yo solo esperaria que me lo divida en dos:

```
Teoría de Control Óptimo   | Teoría de Juegos | NA | NA | NA | NA |NA |NA | NA |NA |
```

tambien intenté el siguiente codigo

```
scan(text = df$Areas, sep = ",", what = "")
```

Pero esto me devuelve un vector y a mi me gustaría tenerlo en el df para convertirlos a factores y poder contarlos y graficarlos y cosas así

Me podrían ayudar por favor
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tenes un error tipográfico en  `separate(Areas, into = c("linea1", "linea2", "linea3", "linea4", "linea5", "linea6", "linea7","linea8", "linea9", "linea10", sep = '\\,' ))` los parentesis de cierre están mal, debería ser así: `separate(Areas, into = c("linea1", "linea2", "linea3", "linea4", "linea5","linea6", "linea7","linea8", "linea9", "linea10"),sep = '\\,')`

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias.